# terraform apply with string template instead of template file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cloud, terraform

In a python script `terraform apply` can be run as follows:

```
from python_terraform import *
...

tf = Terraform(TERRAFORM_DIR)
return_code, stdout, stderr = tf.apply(capture_output=True, skip_plan=True)
```

Is there a way to run `terraform apply` with string template like AWS cloudformation (e.g TemplateBody=*some_string*) in ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass a string of your Terraform config to Terraform to apply it? Terraform can't do that so unless `python-terraform` handles it (doesn't look like it from a glance) you'd instead need to write that string to a `.tf` file in a directory and then apply that.

Comment: I mean exactly that. So there is no other python module or some other way to achieve this ?

Comment: The Python module would still have to write to disk and then clean up anyway so you could just do that yourself if you needed that behaviour.